# How would you go about making these buttons work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem:
http://www.danieldoktor.dk/test2/test2.html

when you push either of the settings buttons it triggers both of the boxes.

I would like an overall code to control the button and the slide-down-and-up-box with a code similar to this, which controls each of the boxes individually instead of controlling them both:

```
$(".someBtnClass").click(function () { 
        if(!$(".someBoxClass").hasClass('header-down')){
            $(".someBoxClass").stop().animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).addClass('header-down'); 
        }
        else{
            $(".someBoxClass").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
        }

    }); 


    $(document).click(function() {
        if($(".someBoxClass").hasClass('header-down')){
            $(".someBoxClass").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
    }
    });

    $(".someBoxClass").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
               // This should not be used unless you do not want
                             // any click events registering inside the div
    });
```

Can this be done with a class?

If not, how can it be made, so the boxes, later can be loaded with php?

EDIT

My markup:
HTML

```
<div class="lists">
        <header class="box_header" id="box1">
            <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
            <div class="setting" id="btn1"></div>
            </header>
 </div>

 <div class="lists">
        <header class="box_header" id="box2">
            <h1>HEADER 2</h1>
            <div class="setting" id="btn2"></div>
            </header>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".setting").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){if(!$(".box_header").hasClass('header-down')){
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).addClass('header-down'); 
    }
    else{
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
    }});
});


$(document).click(function() {
    if($(".box_header").hasClass('header-down')){
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
}
});

$(".box_header").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
           // This should not be used unless you do not want
                         // any click events registering inside the div
});
```

Comment: Try to use id instate of class name. $("#btn1") and $("#btn2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is like this (you should have added this to your question)

```
<header id="box1" class="box_header">
   <h1>HEADER 1</h1>
   <div id="btn1" class="setting"></div>
</header>
```

for each box. So if you click on `.setting` you want to animate only the `.box_header` (parent) of the correct settings button, I presume?

```
$(".setting").on("click", function(){
   if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('header-down')){
      $(this).parent().stop().animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).addClass('header-down');
   } else{
      $(this).parent().stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
   }
});
```

});

Comment: Yeah sorry, but I added the mark-up now.

But this did the trick, thank you so much!!!!!!

This has been a hassle for me until now!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You're selector is grabbing both. You need to tell it to only grab the parent and animate it, instead of grabbing the "box-header" class and animating it

Javascript:

```
$('.setting').on('click', function() {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (!parent.hasClass('header-down')) {
        parent.stop().animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).addClass('header-down'); 
    } else {
        parent.stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/kHV8V/1/

Answer (score 0):

whithout knowing your markup you can try something like this:

```
var box = $(this).parents("div.parent_class").find('.someBoxClass');
```

then replace $('.someBoxClass') with box

Comment: i will just post my code, because I don't know how I would add the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of your jQuery Code

```
// widget 1

 $("#btn1").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){if(!$(".box_header").hasClass('header-down')){
        $("#box1").stop().animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).addClass('header-down'); 
    }
    else{
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
    }});
});


 $("#btn2").each(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(){if(!$(".box_header").hasClass('header-down')){
        $("#box2").stop().animate({height:'100px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).addClass('header-down'); 
    }
    else{
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
    }});
});

$(document).click(function() {
    if($(".box_header").hasClass('header-down')){
        $(".box_header").stop().animate({height:'30px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'linear'}).removeClass('header-down');
}
});

$(".box_header").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
           // This should not be used unless you do not want
                         // any click events registering inside the div
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/evexif/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The click event should be registered with the "ID" of the setting button and not with the css class, as it will apply to all the matched elements. Create a function passing that particular element and replace your $(".someBoxClass") with $(element). For example,

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){animate(this)});

function animate(element){
$(element).stop().....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID instead of class.

```
$("#box1").click(function () { 

$("#box2").click(function () {
```

I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/MTcvu/